# How does Entity Translation module manage translation state?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to understand how the Entity Translation module keeps state for entities. I understand that any given field will have translations stored on the actual fields, but there's also the translations property.

It seems to me that this property has two child properties: (1) original and (2) data. As far as I can see, original holds an original language. But what exactly is the original language, and how does it differ from the entity's language property?

If 'original' is set to 'en', should translations->data['en'] then exist at all? Is english considered a translation?